# custom component reuse with extjs4

Tags: extjs, custom-component, reusability

I have created a custom grid in a javascript file. I want to use it as a xtype on to different panels in seperate js files. If I use it on a single panel, it works fine; but when I use try it use it on different panels at the same time, I get a error in the chrome developer tool console saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isComponent' of undefined
```

My grid definition is as follows:

```
Ext.define('DataBox.view.FootNotes', {
    extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.footNotes',
initComponent : function() {
    this.columns = [ {
        header : 'SL', 
        field : {
            xtype : 'checkbox',
            checked : 'true'
        }
    }, {
        header : 'Symbol',
    }, {
        header : 'Notes', 
    }, ];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

and to include the grid on the panels i use following code

```
initComponent : function() {
    /*  this.footNotesInfoGrid = Ext.create('DataBox.view.FootNotes', {
        colspan: 2,
        border: false,
        frame: 'false'
    }); even tried this */

    Ext.apply(this,{
        items : [{
            xtype : 'footNotes',
            columnWidth : .50,
            id : 'infoFootNotesGrid',
        }]
    }
   }
```

I tried many other ways suggested on different forum discussions.. but my problem stil persists.
Can somebody point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign created objects within a configuration! Use `initComponent` for that!

this line

```
plugins : [ Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit : 1
}) ],
```

should be placed as

```
this.plugins = [ Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit : 1
}) ];
```

anywhere in the `initComponent` body, but before `callParent` is called

**Edit:**

to still allow override do

```
if(!this.plugins) {
    this.plugins = [ Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit : 1
    }) ];
}
```

*Edit*

Avoid using static `id` properties! The framework handle that part for you. Wrap your head around `Ext.ComponentQuery` instead. It will help you to find any Component you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the plugins part. Actually I did not really need it... I had forgotten to remove the code. have removed it now. I have put the code to include the grid inside Ext.apply in initcomponent. I even tried calling a method inside inticomponent that returns an instance of the grid. But neither of these seems to help.

Comment: @vrush you will need to edit your post to reflect these changes ;)

Comment: @vrush I can only make a guess (see my edit); the `id` property may be your problem. A duplicated `id` will cause such issues.