# Multiple Instances of Custom Component in Extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a grid panel named "Teilgewerke". I am able to use it as an item of a panel like

```
{
    xtype:'panel',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },              
    items:[
        {
            //xtype: 'teilgewerkegrid',
            id:'feinplanungPanelTeilgewerkeGrid',
            flex: 2
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 1
        }
    ]

}
```

But now when I try to use it inside another panel, it throws following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isComponent' of undefined
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565787/custom-component-reuse-with-extjs4) on Stackoverflow which is pointing to exact same problem. I tried the solution given in above link, by putting items as

```
initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype:'panel',
                flex: 5,
                border: false,
                padding: '0 20 0 20',
                items:[
                    {
                        xtype: 'text',
                        text: 'Teilgewerke für Aufbau an beteiligte Gruppen senden.',
                    }
                ]               
            },


            Ext.create('PfalzkomApp.view.TeilgewerkeGrid', {
                padding: '0 20 0 20',
                id:'aufbauTabTeilgewerkeGrid',
                flex: 90            
            }),

            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                border: false,
                padding: '0 20 0 20',
                flex: 5             
            }

        ]
    this.callParent();
}
```

But I still have same issue. Can someone point out my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem which I found was to dynamically insert my custom component into the item array of the view(in which I wanted to add).

So in the after render of my view(in which I want to add my custom component), I did this:

```
var view = Ext.getCmp('aufbauTab');

    view.insert(
        view.items.length,
        {
            xtype: 'teilgewerkegrid',
            padding: '0 20 0 20',
            id:'aufbauTabTeilgewerkeGrid',
            flex: 90
        }
    );
```

And it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have should be that there is no `xtype:'text'` predefined in Sencha ExtJS. Please select one of `textfield`, `label`, `container`.

Please do strictly enforce correct indentation throughout your code, or else it will be unreadable soon. Furthermore use the most readable approach for component instantiation, as described below:

If you want to instantiate a custom component, you do it like you instantiate a Sencha component: Using `xtype`.

In the component you define, you give the component an `xtype` name:

```
Ext.define('My.custom.Component',{
    xtype:'teilgewerke'
```

and when you create it, you require the component (so the file is loaded and the xtype is registered with ComponentManager), and then use that very xtype in your items definition:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Component',{
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires:['My.custom.Component'],
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me,{
            items:[{
                xtype:'teilgewerke'
            }]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Please be aware that all custom components you want to instantiate more than once should NEVER contain any absolute `id`; only the relative `itemId`; and they should not use absolute `getCmp`, only relative `down()`, `up()`, `nextSibling()`, `previousSibling()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. About your answer, I have few point. 
There is an xtype:'text' (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.draw.Text).

About code indentation, while pasting it here, it got all this weird but thank you for your advice(I'll try to be more careful.)

In my custom component, instead of xtype, I have set alias property (alias: 'widget.teilgewerkegrid'). This works in my entire application perfectly. There is no duplicate 'id' in my app. I am using 'itemId'. 

I have used your Ext.apply method but i am still getting the error.